# How does a copper piece added in nitric acid change after nitrogen dioxide starts appearing?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, redox

There's an experiment I have no way of performing but want to know its results. The instructions (in short) are:

> Dip a piece of copper in a glass of concentrated nitric acid, $\ce{HNO3}$, using a pincette. When a brown gas starts forming, take out the piece of copper and rinse it with water. Right after that dip it into $\ce{HgNO3}$ solution. Leave it in there for some time and then take it out of the solution. Rinse it with water and wipe it with a napkin.
>
> How does the piece of copper look?

What I've worked out is that the first part can be written as:
$$\ce{Cu (s) + 4HNO3 (aq) -> Cu(NO3)2 (aq) + 2NO2 (g) + 2H2O(l)}$$
and that $\ce{NO2}$ is the brown gas.

What I'm  not sure about is why exactly I'm dipping the copper piece into a solution of $\ce{HgNO3}$ following the above reaction. And why am I rinsing it with water before dipping it into the $\ce{HgNO3}$ solution?

Comment: @student States of aggregation should not be subscripted, it is not wrong, but the [recommendations (Sec. 2.1.)](http://pac.iupac.org/publications/pac/pdf/1982/pdf/5406x1239.pdf) are different.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Thank you, will bear it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Metals often have corrosion on their surface, such as oxides.  By dipping in nitric acid and then rinsing with water you would achieve a true copper metal surface free of oxide or other corrosion products.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely be creating a mercury-copper amalgam similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjkR3ojEfg0)